# Dealing with failed email sending with SMTP-JAVA

Tags: java, email, jakarta-ee, smtp, smtpclient

I am working on a service that sends out emails using SMTP. I set my SMTP properties this way:

```
property.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");

property.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", mailHost);

property.setProperty("mail.from", "xyz@gmail.com");
```

It also works for successful cases. However, when the email sending process fails, I want a notification sent to another one of our customer care email address(say, CC@gmail.com)..

How do I accomplish this. Is there any property among SMTP properties that lets me give like a "failure email address" so that it send a notification to that address, if a failure occurs

Answer (score 0):

Bounced emails usually go back to the `From:` address, so you might change this to, say, "CC@gmail.com". This is also nice because it allows your customers back to you by just hitting "reply" in their mail client.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Does that mean I cannot have a different "from" email address and a "failure-report" email address